# Прописать css атрибуты всем элементам до определенного class

Tags: javascript, css

Есть код, в котором я добавляю css атрибуты (в моем случае `color: red;`) после определенного класса `class="two"` при помощи `~`. Можно ли сделать наоборот (если css не подойдет, то можно использовать javascript), что бы атрибуты добавлялись (перебивали существующие) до `class="two"`?

```css
.main .one {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.main .two~.one {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="two">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
</div>
```

Comment: на css - нет, на js  - можно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не могли бы по подробнее? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с jQuery:

```js
$('.main').children('div').each(function(){ //обходите в цикле дочерние элементы .main
  if($(this).hasClass('two')) { return false; } //если находите элемент с классом two, прерываете цикл
  $(this).css('color','red'); //до этого момента красите элементы красным
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="two">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это бессмысленно лишний код, т.к. в jquery есть `.prevAll(SELECTOR)`

Answer (score 1):

Раз нужно с *JS*, тогда можно попробовать так:

```js
let element = document.querySelector(".two");

while (element = element.previousElementSibling) {    
    if (element.className.includes('one')) {        
        element.classList.add('my-red-class');
    }    
}
```

```css
.main .one {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.main .my-red-class {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="yo">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="two">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нативно через CSS таких операторов нет. Вы можете перевернуть список через `flex` и `column-reverse`, тогда этот эффект сработает.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.main .one {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.main .two~.one {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="two">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но контент переворачивать это не вариант )) Визуально на примере то да, но это не то решение )

Comment: Тогда укажите конкретную задачу. Вы в своем вопросе указали её сильно абстрактно, и для вопроса это будет работать. Но контекст знаете только Вы.

Comment: Я в вопросе указала, что бы атрибуты добавлялись до определенного класса, в вашем примере они не добавляются.

Comment: Визуально они добавляются, не визуально явно в CSS так делать нельзя. Соседний ответ тоже неплохой, но так Вы обязаны будете перебивать свойства. Точно ли нельзя решить задачу другими способами не прибегая к таким конструкциям?

Comment: Мне как раз и нужно перебивать свойства, если нельзя сделать при помощи CSS, то js также приветствуется. Именно по этому я тег "js" и поставила

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказали, средствами CSS пока так сделать нет возможности.

Но можно сначала элементу установить одни правила, а после нужного класса их переназначить.

```css
.main .one {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.main .one {
  color: green;
}

.main .two ~ .one {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="two">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
  <div class="one">word</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно добавлять свойства (перебивать существующие).

Comment: Тогда придётся использовать JS

Comment: А вы можете написать? )